# Able to redirect back to browser after payment done react-native

Tags: react-native

This is the scenario I'm facing

1. I'm on a website and clicked pay from the website
2. The pay button is a dynamic link it took me to the app
3. The user completes the payment in the app

Now I want to redirect the user back to the browser he came from
How can I achieve this in react-native

I have seen so many payments apps behave this way just wondering how to do it in RN

Comment: Have you looked into deeplinking? I think that's one way to achieve it. The browser can call the URL and deeplinking checks if he app is on the phone and you can pass parameters in the URL to process in the app.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/

Comment: In the part where I have to go to the app with data that was successful, what I wanted is to redirect back to the previous app that I came from once the task(payment) is done just like it happens in so many payment apps